# leave animation does not apply to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

```
'use strict';

angular.module('eikonApp')
  .animation('.pageAnimation',function() {

    return {

      leave: function(element, done) {
        console.log("LEAVE");


        element.find('.hidden-elm').each( function(i,v) {
          var self = $(this);
          var animationTypeExit = self.attr('animation-type');
          animationTypeExit =  animationTypeExit.replace(/In/g,"Out");

         self.removeClass(self.attr('animation-type'));
         self.addClass(animationTypeExit);


          done();
        });



      },


      enter: function(element, done) {
        console.log("ENTER");
        element.find('.hidden-elm').each(function(i, v) {
           var self = $(this);

          setTimeout(function() {
            var effect = 'animated ' + self.attr('animation-type');
            self.show();
            self.addClass(effect);
          }, 100 * i);
          done();
        // console.log(self);
       });

      }


    }
  });
```

I wrote this service to add animations to a angular app  view enter and leave events. When enter event animations are added to the DOM successful. In leaving event animations does not apply to the DOM.

I am trying to create animation like this app
http://www.mtwapps.com/indigo-series/index.html

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question, I cannot really understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin  actually i want to create page elements animations like this app http://www.mtwapps.com/indigo-series/index.html